# React Native fetch gives TypeError on Android

Tags: android, error-handling, react-native, fetch

I've been puzzling over this for quite some time. Trying to make a `POST` request to my local HTTP server with React Native's `fetch`, but constatly get `TypeError`.

Here is how i go about my request.

```
onSignIn(credentials) {
  const host = 'http://192.168.0.106';
  const namespace = '/api/v1';
  const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  fetch(host + namespace + '/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(function (user) {
    dispatch(registerSuccess(user));
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch(registerError(err));
  });
}
```

I know that the IP address is correct, since I've made a request with Postman on my computer. Also none of the answers I've found helped me any. I'm running this on Android 5.1, if that changes something.

Please, little bit of help would go a long way.

Comment: Are you testing from a real device ?

Comment: Yes, yes I am. On Xiaomi Note 3 Pro, to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a weird one, but it may help someone. I'm not quite sure what the issue was here, but I've managed to resolve this by pinging my Phone from the computer, with this:

```
ping 192.168.0.100
```

After that, somehow the API requests suddenly went through. Obviously the IP address for your phone may differ, and the pings have to be successful, hope it may help someone

I realise that this doesn't answer what really was the issue, but it most likely is some sort of router issues or local network config, hard to say.